# Subversion user authentcation hook?

Tags: svn

I don't know if this is possible... but I hope it is. And the use case is odd, I know, but I need to make it happen. :)

I have a server with a REST interface that manages users. I can use it to test if a user is "authenticated" or not. Pass a login/password to a URL and it'll return a HTTP status code.

That's the easy part, I can make a bash/python script to do that. Easy Peasy.

But I'm stumped if there's a way to make subversion use this?

Basically I want subversion to use this Script/REST interface to authenticate if a user can have access to the repository (ideally the script).

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Which server at backend? Svnserver can't use external authentications, AFAICR with Apache you can have custom externals authentication-agents (I'm too lazy to RTFM now in order to provide URL to module)

Comment: Ah, so you're saying use Apache to do the authentication, not Subversion. That makes sense. Good idea!